# Rails Neo4j.rb Serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

In Active node how we can implement JSON serializers like active modal

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Or any other way to send customized API response?

Right now I am doing it by making custom method in controller in which response is made after iterations (no. of records)

```
posts.map{|x| serialize_post(x) }

def serialize_post (post)
  {
    id: post.id,
    name: post.name
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActiveNode` gem is based off of `ActiveModel`, so you should be able to simply call `to_json` on it with all of the arguments that that supports.  You should also be able to define `as_json` and `from_json` methods:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Separately, I'm also a big fan of the JSON API standard, so for that you might want to check out the [jsonapi-serializers gem](https://github.com/fotinakis/jsonapi-serializers)

**Edit:**

Active model serilaizer Gem also fulfill the purpose

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: any way to include this in base controller jsonapi-serializers I am using ActionController::Metal or any other gem for it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but this example seems to integration `jsonapi-serializers` with Rails: https://github.com/fotinakis/jsonapi-serializers#rails-example